# showing all Y axis in bar chart - MSChart

Tags: mschart

How can I show all text values of Y axis in the bar chart shown in the image

[image]

Comment: I'm seeing the text values in the image...where exactly do you want them?

Comment: also it occurs to me when the number of items is more than ten, it worked with the solution of Memmed

Answer (score 3):

Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;